# RSA key encryption issue in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption

I'm having an issue with using RSA encryption in Python 3 vs Python 2.7. They return different values.

If I run the following code below on both Python 2.7 and Python 3 I get very different results:

```
def bin2hex(s):
return "".join([hex(ord(c))[2:].zfill(2) for c in s])

KEY = """-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC81t5iu5C0JxYq5/XNPiD5ol3Z
w8rw3LtFIUm7y3m8o8wv5qVnzGh6XwQ8LWypdkbBDKWZZrAUd3lybZOP7/82Nb1/
noYj8ixVRdbnYtbsSAbu9PxjB7a/7LCGKsugLkou74PJDadQweM88kzQOx/kzAyV
bS9gCCVUguHcq2vRRQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"""

from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
encrypter = PKCS1_v1_5.new(RSA.importKey(KEY))
print (bin2hex(str(encrypter.encrypt('1231231231234'.encode()))))
```

**Result when executing using Python 2.7**:

> 3686eac493f8bb874c830b55652ee3d6dedbf3b079d7acd113a53e716f4e997a440a1e53815e80a6f81121eca1a6b5d89cf08a341b7d546c66e849334b7992936d544e734df63ac803d611013d59249b5b0a8441335908560668f2983cd185b57391dc1bda7caeb405a149eb015eef0198bdfd480d3a280fda400c18b8ae9d90

**Result when running the same code on Python 3:**

> 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

Does anyone know why the output differs depending upon the version of Python being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that in Python 2 "encrypter.encrypt" method returns a string and in Python 3 it returns bytes. To get the hex string out of bytes you can just call .hex() method. In addition, there is no need to write your own "bin2hex" function for Python 2, you can use .encode('hex'):

```
encrypted = encrypter.encrypt('1231231231234'.encode())
# encrypted = encrypted.encode('hex')  # python 2
encrypted = encrypted.hex()  # python 3
print(len(encrypted), encrypted)
```

In both interpreters the length will be 256 hex chars, or 128 bytes.

Also, RSA encryption includes some randomness so every time you encrypt the same text you will get different output but with the same length of 128 bytes.

Comment: hex() is not available in python 3.4 it shows error like 'bytes' object has no attribute 'hex'

Comment: There are a lot of options to convert bytes to hex. For example, `import codecs; codecs.encode(b'foo', 'hex').decode()`